# Drag controls from container and drop/draw them on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to allow user to drag icons from one div container and drop and draw them on canvas keeping the original icon intact. The icons are added dynamically on table. I also want to give effect of icon dragging with cursor when i drag the icon.When i use " helper: 'clone'" property i get the effect but the dropped position is incorrect and when i remove this property the original icon is removed.

My parent container for icons

```
     <div id="dvEquipmentTool" style="removed: absolute; border: 1px solid rgb(173, 201, 247);
    display: block; background-color: white; height: 400px; z-index: 50000; padding: 3px;
    removed 100px; removed 50px; width: 200px !important;" class="ui-draggable">
    <table id="tbEquipmentTool" border="0" style="background-color: White; padding-left: 10px;
        max-height: 400px !important;">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tRow1">
                <td>
                    <img src="" id="imgEquipIcon1" class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative; left: 473px;
                        top: 183px;">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="lblImgEquipName1" class="label">10-FL-105-A20</span><span id="lblImgEquipID1"
                        class="label" style="display: none;">100200</span>
                </td>
                <td width="10px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tRow2">
                <td>
                    <img src="" id="imgEquipIcon2" class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="lblImgEquipName2" class="label">10-FL-3111-A20</span><span id="lblImgEquipID2"
                        class="label" style="display: none;">100199</span>
                </td>
                <td width="10px">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript function to make images draggable

```
    $("img[id^=imgEquipIcon]").each(function () {


    $(this).draggable({ containment: "#dvContainer", scroll: false,//helper: 'clone',
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var stoppos = $(this).position();
            alert(stoppos.left+","+ stoppos.top);

            var img = new Image();
            img.src = this.src;
            createEquipIcon(img, stoppos.left, stoppos.top);

        }

    });

});

function createEquipIcon(img, X, Y) {
    var dv = document.createElement('div');

    $(dv).css('top', Y);
    $(dv).css('left', X);
    $(dv).css('cursor', 'move');
    $(dv).css('position', 'absolute');
    $(dv).css('background-color', 'red');

    dv.appendChild(img);
    var index = img.id.replace('imgEquipIcon', '');

    var container = document.getElementById('dvContainer');
    container.appendChild(dv);
   //code for drawing on canvas goes here

}
```

Canvas for drawing images

```
    <div id="dvContainer" runat="server" style="overflow: visible; background-repeat: no-repeat">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000px" height="600px">
          <b> *Your browser doesn't support canvas. Please switch to different browser.</b>
        </canvas>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/cyur7/

Before drag and after drag:

[image][image]

**Make an html toolbar**

- create a div to hold all the tool icons.
- create img elements for each of your tools and put them in the toolbar div
- give all the tool img's the class="tool"

*Html toolbar-div with tool-imgs:*

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <img class="tool" width=32 height=32 src="equipment1.jpg">
    <img class="tool" width=32 height=32 src="equipment1.jpg">
    <img class="tool" width=32 height=32 src="equipment1.jpg">
</div>
```

**Make all .tools draggable with jQuery**

- select all the .tools in jquery ($tools)
- make all .tools draggable
- give all the .tools a data payload to with their index in $tools.

*Make all .tools draggable:*

```
    // select all .tool's

    var $tools=$(".tool");

    // make all .tool's draggable

    $tools.draggable({ helper:'clone' });


    // assign each .tool its index in $tools

    $tools.each(function(index,element){
        $(this).data("toolsIndex",index);
    });
```

**Make the canvas a drop target:**

```
    // make the canvas a dropzone
    $canvas.droppable({
        drop:dragDrop,
    });
```

**When dropped, draw the img on the canvas**

- get the drop point of the droppable
- get the data payload of the droppable (the index of the dropped item in $tools)
- use context.drawImage to draw the dropped image on the canvas

*Drop handler*

```
    // handle a drop into the canvas
    function dragDrop(e,ui){

        // get the drop point (be sure to adjust for border)
        var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX)-1;
        var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);

        // get the drop payload (here the payload is the $tools index)
        var theIndex=ui.draggable.data("toolsIndex");

        // drawImage at the drop point using the dropped image 
        ctx.drawImage($tools[theIndex],x,y,32,32);

    }
```