# Using Accordion inside canvas

Tags: html, canvas, accordion

When we use the accordion, we call it using an id inside a div

```
<div id="accordion">
```

What I want to do is using accordion inside a canvas element. Canvas tag already calls its id, I don't have any idea how to solve this issue.

The main purpose is to have an area on the left where the images are sorted in three sections, which will be put inside an accordion. On the right, I drawed a grid inside another canvas element. This is where the images will be dropped. 
Here is the code, I stopped here, and I don't know for what reason jsfiddle only shows one canvas although the drawing of the grid is correct. I apologize for my bad code.

http://jsfiddle.net/uS4er/4/

Comment: Why do you want to put a div inside a canvas element? You will loose any interactive functions if you render the HTML onto a canvas. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: I didn't mean that, I think I was not clear, sorry. All I want to do is to put accordion inside canvas element.

Comment: Can you add your current code to the question and clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: Okay, I just did. The code works fine when edited in Notepad++, if you change the size of the canvas the grid will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The jQueryUI accordion wiget will not operate inside an html canvas.**

*An alternate plan:*

You could create your image-source-accordion outside and left of the canvas.

Then use jQuery draggable plus canvas as a dropzone to copy an image from your toolbox and draw it on the canvas.

This link shows how to use jqueryUI draggable to "drop" an img element on the canvas:

[Drag controls from container and drop/draw them on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093935/drag-controls-from-container-and-drop-draw-them-on-canvas/22105097#22105097)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. It's good now. Many thanks :-)

Comment: can I draw canvases (because I need to use EaselJS to manipulate images) inside the sections of an accordion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but Yes, you can put canvases inside an accordion.  Then you can use those image-canvas instead of img elements as sources for your main grid canvas. For example, if you have a canvas element in the accordion with id of canvasImg1, then you can draw that canvas-image on the main grid canvas like this: var cImg1=document.getElementById("canvasImg1");   mainContext.drawImage(cImg1,100,100);

Comment: Good. Well, yes, I need the sections of the accordion to be canvases, so I can load inside them images, that are going to be dragged inside an external canvas. It's complicate I know.

Comment: To be specific, each "image" inside the accordion must be a separate canvas.  jQueryUI will only drag a whole element, not something inside that element.  If you have 1 canvas in the accordion with 5 images in that 1 canvas, then all 5 images will be dragged onto the grid-canvas.  So...each image you want to drag must be a separate canvas.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the result you want, but this will render a `<div id="accordion">` on a `<canvas>` element, or any other content on a canvas. **http://jsfiddle.net/L93gA/**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
    "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size: 12px;' id='accordion'>" +
                 "Content of accordion" +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;
```

Based on the example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: What should I put in "Content of accordion"? I tried putting my data but it's just formatted text, no accordion functionality.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't know what you want to do. Do you want to put a canvas inside a div that you can collapse/minimize like an accordion to hide the canvas?

Comment: I have two canvas elements: in the first one, I need to have an accordion of three sections (Build, Equipments, and Sensors), in each section there will be images to be dragged to the second canvas. This second canvas is a big grid. Is this doable?

Comment: It sounds like you need three canvases and put them inside three elements to handle the accordion functionality